# Creating image slide show using jQuery plugin cycle2. Though the link was deleted but another one from Cloudfare also does not work

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-plugins, web-frontend

I have been trying to create an image slide show using jQuery cycle slide show but its not happening.

The script I am using is :

```js
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=
    , initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HTML&CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
       
            <div class="logo">
               <a href="grouping_elements.html">
                <img src="1.png" height="100px" width="100px">

               </a>
            </div>
        </header>
      
    
    <div class="search">
        <form>
            <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="search here....">
            <input type="submit" name="t">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="searchfix">

    </div>
   
    <nav class="main-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">home</a>
               
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <a href="#">about us</a>
                <ul class="drop">
                    <li><a href="#">service 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">service 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">service 3</a></li>

                </ul> 
            </li>
            <li>
                
                <a href="#">phone number</a>
                
            </li>
            <li>
                
                <a href="#">linked in</a>
             
            </li>
            <li>
                
                <a href="#">social media</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="banner cycle-slideshow">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/10/09/11/30/spider-7508942_960_720.jpg" alt="banner1" height="500px" width="700px">
        <br>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/03/19/18/23/mountain-biking-95032_960_720.jpg" alt="banner 2" height="500px" width="700px">
    </section>
    <section>
        <article>
            <main>
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus laboriosam eos ullam voluptatum 
                    ratione blanditiis ipsa voluptate! Cupiditate eius recusandae at repudiandae iste repellat quidem quaerat 
                    commodi dolores id, asperiores minus odio nostrum temporibus ipsum impedit, labore voluptate unde earum! 
                    Nostrum odit omnis at voluptatem sint quis eaque quaerat dolores.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus vitae sed ipsam corrupti, eos quod 
                    recusandae earum porro odit dicta voluptas eligendi, temporibus quos nemo. Mollitia, reprehenderit?
                     Explicabo aliquid quia fugit quis pariatur qui quo, eligendi quos voluptate necessitatibus dolorem vero 
                     facilis molestias facere ipsum deleniti libero voluptatum similique vel, repellat placeat tenetur. 
                     At iure, ipsa dolorum placeat facere debitis vitae impedit fuga et officiis non illum sapiente eveniet 
                     eligendi ea mollitia enim a? A provident dolore at, voluptate quaerat suscipit omnis, consequuntur deleniti 
                     aliquid saepe labore repellendus molestias mollitia doloremque consectetur nihil nisi molestiae ipsum 
                     laboriosam praesentium modi enim?
                </p>
            </main>
            <aside>
                <div>
                    <h3>widget</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">2018</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2019</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2020</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </aside>
        </article>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <div>
            <h3>menu</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">hiring</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>menu</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">hiring</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>menu</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">hiring</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <address>
                milington downstreet-10 houseno.12
                <p><a href="mailto:subhashreepati2912@outlook.com">mail us</a></p>
                <p><a href="telno.:9398709384">call us</a></p>
            </address>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <div>
        <p><small>Copyright &copy; 2020. All rights reserved</small></p>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first image remains stagnant and doesn't change to the next. Please help me out in this anyone it will be a great help. I was writing the code from the help of Udemy Front End Development course by Fateh Gabriel.